# Is it possible to Check-in and Check-out the current form from the InfoPath browser editor?

Tags: infopath, check-in, check-out

A coworker has been tasked with adding check-in and check-out functionality from within an InfoPath 2010 form.  Is this possible?

This is a typical use case:

1. User is browsing a SharePoint Form Library and wants to edit a form
2. User forgets to checkout form before opening the form in the browser
3. User wants to edit form immediate without going back to SP UI to check-out document manually.
4. User clicks on an 'edit' button we've added to the form which sets all fields to editable.  *This should also check-out the form from SharePoint.*
5. User goes about editing the document, and clicks submit (another custom button, from what I understand).  At this point the form is submitted *and should be checked-in to Sharepoint.*

Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in List Advanced Settings to require check-out to edit a document. This would solve the problem of the user forgetting. I am not sure you can check-out the document once it is open but it can be done a few ways:

- sandbox code-behind in the InfoPath form
- the Lists.ASMX web service